# Can I use a conic gradient with inline styling?

Tags: css, inline, css-gradients

I just play with CSS.  I'm no professional at all, so please pardon me if this is a dumb/obvious question.

Problem: The blogging platform for which I'm developing disallows any external style sheets, as well as the use of the `<style>` tag, so I'm forced to do everything inline.

I've been toying with a simple percentage circle from CodePen (BobbyHo's [CSS Percentage Circle](https://codepen.io/bobby1030/pen/amkaGN)) which uses conic-gradient, and everything (even an inline adapted version) looks fabulous after forking it on CodePen.  But the instant I drop it onto the blogging site, the conic gradient disappears.

```
<div id="element" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 50%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: conic-gradient(#39DE57 40%, #513BB3 0);">
    <div class="inner" style="width: 180px; height: 180px; position: relative; background-color: #D6D6D6; border-radius: 50%;font-size: 3em; color: #4F4F4F; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        40%
    </div>
</div>
```

Which suggests gradients are a no go for inline styles.  I know they're handled like an image and not a color, but I really thought you could do this.  Am I mistaken?  Or am I missing something extremely obvious?

Comment: Inline styles are fine in this example and should work correctly. Perhaps there is a problem with your blogging platfor that is parsing document before publishing and cuts off some styles?

Comment: Sounded about right to me, so I tested with jsfiddle, and alas, no joy: https://jsfiddle.net/5r9n5k20/

Comment: This isn't embarrassing at all.  Near as I can tell (and someone who knows more, please feel free to correct me) conic-gradient only works in conjunction with a polyfill, and are thus far unsupported.  If anyone has _another_ means of achieving a pie chart with only inline CSS, though, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work perfectly.

```
<div id="progress-spinner" style={{
    background: `conic-gradient(rgb(3, 133, 255) ${progress}%, rgb(242, 242, 242) ${progress}%)`
}}></div>
```

You can even put it into the template literal and manipulate the % of color stops, like I did with my  'progress' variable